# Retrieving the values from the list view SharePoint 2010 using object model

Tags: visual-studio, list-view, sharepoint-enterprise, object-model

I have a list (tick_gen) which has a view called "tick_dView" this view just has one row.  How can I fetch the value of "Tick_id" column using SharePoint object model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first get a view, next create an SPQuery object using this view's query and then get your item.
Code will look like this one:

```
var view = list.Views["tick_dView"];
var query = new SPQuery();
query.Query = view.Query;
query.RowLimit = view.RowLimit;
var item = list.GetItems(query).Cast<SPListItem>().FirstOrDefault();
if(item != null)
{
   var tickId = item["Tick_id"];
}
```

You can also pass view directly into spquery constructor (and ommit 3 and 4th lines), but doing this you must be sure, that `Tick_id` field is present in the `tick_dView`. If not, you will need to specify additional view fields for spquery.

Comment: it worked..though i was getting error when i try to cast..the Cast was not comming up in the intelleigence so i went ahead and used ur logic with litle syntax change   var  list = web.Lists["tick_list"];
var view = list.Views["tick_dView"];
var query = new SPQuery();
query.Query = view.Query;
query.RowLimit = view.RowLimit;
SPListItemCollection sp1 = list.GetItems(query);
foreach (SPListItem listitem in sp1)
{
string IDVAL = listitem[Tick_id].ToString();
}

Comment: you need to add `using System.Linq;`, sorry I forgot to mention it.